# Call a method at fixed time in Java

Tags: java

How do I  call a method at a particular time?

For example to call the method at 6:00 and 13:00.

I'm working at a desktop application for Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Timer`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) classes. You can schedule a thread to execute at a specific time, or repeatedly.

```
public class Alarm {
    Timer _timer;

    public Alarm() {

        // Create a Date corresponding to 10:30:00 AM today.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Date alarmTime = calendar.getTime();

        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.schedule(new AlarmTask(), alarmTime);
    }

    class AlarmTask extends TimerTask {
        /**
         * Called on a background thread by Timer
         */
        public void run() {
            // Do your work here; it's 10:30 AM!

            // If you don't want the alarm to go off again
            // tomorrow (etc), cancel the timer
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to to use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It's effectively the same as `Timer` or `TimerTask`, but it does allow for a description of what must run using a `cron` style syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 1.5 there is a preferable way, if you need to be more strict: [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> This class is preferable to Timer  when multiple worker threads are needed, or when the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor (which this class extends) are required.

There you choose between `scheduleAtFixedRate()` and `scheduleWithFixedRate()`. More details on the usage can be found in the linked javadoc.