# How initiate an action at a particular time every day in c#.net

Tags: c#, triggers

I am looking to do an action on every day at a particular time like triggers in sql, but here i am looking to do this in c#.net, can any one please help me,

Thanks

Comment: Write your own .NET Windows Service.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your actions? triggers happen when you do CRUD operation in your data, not in particular time.

Comment: Actually i need to perform an action at 00:00 hours of every day that means once a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you are creating loop and then check if it's time for your action. It should be alwasy running process (service, or application in tray, etc).

It depends on how clear you need to be in your timer: if it needs to be second in second you need to create interval in 1 second and in `Elapsed` handler check you target time with current one, if true - fire alarm (event).

Comment: Actually i need to perform an action at 00:00 hours of every day that means once a day,

Comment: So if it should be exactly in 00:00 you need to set interval in 1 minute, if it's OK to run it in any minute till the 01:00 - you can set to 1 hour.. So, I prefer 1 minute, it's not heavy operation to compare 2 dates.

Comment: btw, similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c

Comment: and complete tutorial about it: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Timer-Objects-in-Windows-Services-with-C-sharp-dot-NET/

Comment: I think i understand some thing that I need to create windows service and schedule that service... am I going in right direction?

Comment: You actually not scheduling the service, you making timer inside the service which will perform your scheduling. In other words you are making your own scheduler.

Comment: Yeah I got it the link you posted is really got a good explanation and top be frank a good solution for my scenario, thank you very much

Comment: I think it would be much easier to just create the app that performs your action and then use the Windows Task Scheduler to have it executed each day at midnight!