# How to log a datetime and on daily base

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, logging

I have to develop a file that logs daily and inside of the log file it shows me a date and time of every log.
I got sofar that I create a log file with this code :

```
Stream iStream = File.Open("C:\\TEST\\logfiles\\Test_Plugin.txt", FileMode.Append); 
StreamWriter iWriter = new StreamWriter(iStream);
```

I do get a logfile but there is no date time the out put is just bunch of messages underneath each other.
Also I would like to log these on daily basis. This plugin would run on the server.
thanks

Comment: Why can't you just write, for example, `DateTime.Now.ToString()` to your log file?
Regarding your second question: look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c).
I'd also advice you to have a look at specific logging frameworks like log4net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not start off by writing a static method that can do the logging so the logic is encapsulated in one place like this:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Log(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\TEST\\logfiles\\Test_Plugin.txt", true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"), string.Format(format, args));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in your code like this:

```
Logger.Log("hello this is a test");
```

It will also support string format expressions e.g:

```
Logger.Log("a: {0}  b: {1} c:{2}", "a", "bb", "ccc");
```