# schedule an automated process from a wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I have a wpf application that runs fine. One of the buttons runs a process that takes some time. I have decided to use Windows Task Schedule to run this process in the morning before I get into work.

The other tasks that I have scheduled are all console applications. How do I schedule the process to run from a wpf application as I do not wish to copy my code into a console application?

**What I have tried so far**

I have added a console application to my project and added the line below in the Debug > Start Options > Command line arguments.

```
 /AUTORUN TRUE
```

In the schedule task Add arguments text box I've added the line below.

```
  /AUTORUN TRUE
```

When I run my scheduled task runs it just loads my WPF application though and nothing else.

Comment: Can find a WINFORMS example for the same here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c