# How run a task everyday at a particular time without using sheduler or windowservice

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application

I want a task (.exe) to run everyday at 8:55 am which will span over 30 miniutue.so i created a console application which will start that task(.exe)  by using `process.start()`.I don't want a sheduler or windowservice rather i am happy with a console application.But the logic used in console application some times fails ie that is not invoking the task (.exe).I create infinite loop by using `while(true)`. The code i am posting down(console code),how to correct it

```
while (true)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 8 & DateTime.Now.Minute == 55 && DateTime.Now.Second == 0)
                {
                    Process.Start(".exe");//not real code
                }
                else
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

**EDIT**
 I need to run the task only one time by using console application,not more than that in a day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method daily, at specific time, in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c)

Comment: You're missing the second mark.

Comment: @Nikola it is not a duplicate , i have edited my question

Comment: @peter, in the said question there are examples how to achieve this without using scheduler :)

Comment: @Nikola that contains an approch,but see serhiyb answer down , very simple and contain less number of lines.But i have to verify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        while (true)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var schedule = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 8, 55, 00);
            if (schedule < now) schedule = schedule.AddDays(1);

            Thread.Sleep(schedule.Subtract(now));

            Process.Start(".exe");
        }
```

Comment: Faulty. Only start the exe inside the if.

Comment: @Tobias Knauss, give it another thought. This code will run only once per day. No need in if.

Answer (score 2):

Because your condition is missing seconds. Thread.Sleep(1000) won't guarantee it will be paused exactly when each second is 0, so you need to be smarter than that.

Comment: How can i get rid of that?

Comment: The first most obvious method - check that current time is equal or greater than 8:55 am, then start the process.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss that might not work either, depending on how busy CPU is and how much attention your process will get.

Comment: @aloneguid I need to run the task only one time by using console application,not more than that in a day

Comment: You're right, but it will increase the chance a lot. He could additionaly skip the seconds check and set a flag to remember that it was run at that day.

Comment: @peter you can remember the day the task was run in a variable and don't trigger again. If you want more flexibility check out http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ i've used it many times for scheduling.