# script to insert a video on the site automatically when it is published on the other site?

Tags: javascript, html

I insert videos from another site on my site with the agreement of the owner of course.
Currently I do this manually but is there a script to insert a video on the site automatically when it is published on the other site
Thank you

Comment: You should show us the script you are using for this. Anyway if you are referring a URI you have nothing to worry about because when that resource changes your scripts is going to refer the correct one.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of software is off-topic on SO. You should first ask yourself how you're gonna know (automatically) it is published on the other site. Feed? Scraping? Ping by other site? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do the following.

1)create a normal script to irritate through the current videos the site has.

2)a function to automatically upload a video to your site,

3)a console app to supervise it:

[How to call a method daily, at specific time, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c)

you need (at some point at time) save all the current videos that are on his
site (maybe on xml),
and then create a console app to do the following every predetermined time lapse (a minute , a second , or an hour):

1)get the list of videos from the site;

2)compare it with the current list of videos;

3)if this list is different from the one we currently have -
 upload the extra videos and save it as the new list;

you can make the console app or have the other site's
administrator send you a post http request to an
asp / whatever you are using page, that calls the other
function that uploads a video automatically.

in order to do any of those I need to know:

1)how do you currently get the published videos from his site.

2)how do you upload a video to your site.

3)what language you are using.

I can't write any magic code to work on your website because
I don't know how your website works - something you
should have specified inside the question.