# execute lines of code in c# or MVC 5 automatically on 12 AM daily basis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created one class. I can manually execute that class from any controller and  its work properly. But now i want to schedule this task automatically and without depending on controller. Is there any functionality in mvc 5 for trigger specific class at fixed time ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no built-in triggering mechanism in asp.net for running code at a given time (a "job"). You need to build your own or use other software (CRON or Windows Scheduler).

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243354/7147323) might help you.
Cheers!

Comment: i am building web application.Is there any alternative solution ? execute it without any external software.

or something like ajax timer which help to run class automatically ?

Comment: @mb14  that reference is very useful for desktop application. for MVC 5 web application is there any functionality same like Application Idle ? Because lines of code is written in simple c# class and separate  from all controller. i just want to execute that class without involving any controller and automatically

Comment: The only way I am aware of is what @gunr2171 mentioned. Using scheduled task or other CRON job

Comment: What you're asking asp.net to do is fundamentally different from what it's designed to do. asp.net is a client/server architecture. It is only going to run code when a client browser asks it to do something. Unless you modify the underlying engine, it doesn't run code in the background.

Comment: thanks buddy u cleared my confusion @gunr2171

Answer (score 0):

> in a ASP.NET web app, there are methods to "simulate" sending out scheduled events - check out this [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)
>
> and of course, you can also just simply "roll your own" in any .NET app - check out this [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6507/NET-Scheduled-Timer) for a sample implementation

Taken from the link provided in comments.