# Quartz C# Run every hour

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I need to trigger a job each hour by starting a specific hour. For example, it starts at 10:00 pm and runs at 11:00 pm, 00:00, 01:00 am, 02:00 am (and so on).

I already tried two options but the job is not triggered.

```
//second try

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, Hour, Minutes 0);
            trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "JobExample")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInHours(1))
             .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(dt))

//first try

        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("job1", "JobExample")
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule( x => x.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(Hour, Minutes))
         .WithIntervalInHours(1))
```

Comment: `00:00, 00:01am` ...these are not 1 hour apart. Is it a typo? And what does "doesn't work" mean. The job is not triggered? It triggers but at the wrong intervals? You get errors? Please clarify

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The trigger is just being created its calling . Build() at the end. You can try this tool https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz to easily see with what scheudle the trigger is being built

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method daily, at specific time, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c)

Comment: Sorry, I already updated my question

Comment: The jobs are triggered, but not when I need. For example, in first try the job started at 22pm (for example), it was triggered at 23 pm and notihing more. In the next day started again at 22pm.
In second try, the job does not triggered in the next hour...

Answer (score 2):

I think you missing

> .RepeatForever()

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithIdentity("trigger8") // because group is not specified, "trigger8" will be in the default group
.StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenHourDate(null)) // get the next even-hour (minutes and seconds zero ("00:00"))
.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
    .WithIntervalInHours(2)
    .RepeatForever())
// note that in this example, 'forJob(..)' is not called 
//  - which is valid if the trigger is passed to the scheduler along with the job  
.Build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger, job);
```

[simpletriggers](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I need that trigger start a specific hour:minute and then, repeat each hour:minute (forever)

Comment: that's possible , just add ".RepeatForever()" in your trigger and try .TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("job1", "JobExample").WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(1).RepeatForever()).StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(dt));

Comment: I will try ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try use chron expression.

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,22,23 ? * * *")
    .ForJob("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();
```

[Cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)
[Freeformatter cron expression](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)