# C# is it possible to run a program every day in a specified time are left visual studio open?

Tags: c#

I created a program that runs every day at 5:00 p.m. but when I debug the program the console always stays open
I want to debug once is close my pc and demin when I open my pc without running the program another time the application runs at 5:00 pm automatically

```
var DailyTime = "5:00:00";
var timeParts = DailyTime.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

while (true)
{
    var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
    var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day,
    int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));
    TimeSpan ts;

    if (date > dateNow)
        ts = date - dateNow;
    else
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        ts = date - dateNow;
    }

    Task.Delay(ts).Wait();
    Copie();
    FichierTrace.Close();
    Console.Read();
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c). It might help you.

Comment: I tried that but when I run the program the console stays open I don't want that
 what I want is even I shut down my pc and the next day it turned on without making another execution at 5:00 the program will run by itself

Comment: it's not a Winforms application
it's a console application without form

Comment: It stays open, because you need an input to `Console.Read()`. Remove that line and it will close automatically. You also have an infinite loop => will stay open. Remove all the timing code, which doesn't work anyway. Then use Windows Task Scheduler to execute it according to schedule.

Comment: Everything after _"...always stays open..."_ makes no sense to me.  It's probably staying open due to the endless loop caused by `while (true)` with no sign of return/break

Answer (score 2):

I have two possible solutions for you, but first, you must do the following either way:

1. Throw away all the "timing" code.
2. Throw away the infinite loop 'while(true)...`
3. Boil it down to the *task* that should be done *and nothing else*.

Then you can either:

1. Use Windows Task Scheduler and setup a trigger to execute the program each day at 5:00 PM

Or

2. Write a Windows Service around it, that you register to be started automatically on boot. That service then uses some scheduling framework like for example Quartz<sup>1</sup> to schedule a job that will perform the actual Task.

If you think about it you will probably find that 1.) is *much* easier to do. 2.) Gives you different options but I think plain console program and Windows Scheduler should be sufficient here. And you can still evolve it later on.

Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I am not affiliated with the Quartz.NET project. It's just the one I happen to know.

Comment: Please can you help me with an example code because I don't know what to modify on my code

Comment: @sara Well, your snippet is not complete. But for all I know, what should be left of it would be `Copie();`

Comment: copie() this is the method I want to run every day in an hour

Comment: @sara Exactly. If you use the Windows Task Scheduler, that's all you need.