# Call method at date/time

Tags: java, datetime, future, java-time

I am searching for a *modern* way to execute a given method at a given date/time (`ZonedDateTime` in particular).

I am aware of the `Timer` class and the *Quartz* library, as shown here (the threads include full solutions):

- [Java - Execute method on specific date [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295187/java-execute-method-on-specific-date)
- [Call a method at fixed time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331736/call-a-method-at-fixed-time-in-java)

But those threads are rather old and do not utilize the new Java features and library elements since then. In particular, it would be very handy to get hands on any kind of `Future` object, since they provide a simple mechanism to cancel them.

So please do not suggest solutions involving `Timer` or *Quartz*. Also, I'd like to have a *vanilla* solution, not using any external libraries. But feel free to also suggest those for the sake of Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `ScheduledExecutorService`

You can use the `ScheduledExecutorService` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)) class, which is available since Java 5. It will yield a `ScheduledFuture` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html)) which can be used to monitor the execution and also cancel it.

In particular, the method:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> schedule​(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

which

> Submits a one-shot task that becomes enabled after the given delay.

But you can also look into the other methods, depending on the actual use case (`scheduleAtFixedRate` and versions accepting `Callable` instead of `Runnable`).

Since Java 8 (Streams, Lambdas, ...) this class becomes even more handy, due to the availability of easy conversion methods between the old `TimeUnit` and the newer `ChronoUnit` (for your `ZonedDateTime`), as well as the ability to provide the `Runnable command` as lambda or method reference (because it is a `FunctionalInterface`).

---

### Example

Let's have a look at an example doing what you ask for:

```
// Somewhere before the method, as field for example
// Use other pool sizes if desired
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public static ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleFor(Runnable runnable, ZonedDateTime when) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // Use a different resolution if desired
    long secondsUntil = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(now, when.toInstant());

    return scheduler.schedule(runnable, secondsUntil, TimeUnit.of(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

A call is simple:

```
ZonedDateTime when = ...
ScheduledFuture<?> job = scheduleFor(YourClass::yourMethod, when);
```

You can then use the `job` to monitor the execution and also cancel it, if desired. Example:

```
if (!job.isCancelled()) {
    job.cancel(false);
}
```

---

### Notes

You can exchange the `ZonedDateTime` parameter in the method for `Temporal`, then it also accepts other date/time formats.

Do not forget to shutdown the `ScheduledExecutorService` when you are done. Else you will have a thread running, even if your main program has finished already.

```
scheduler.shutdown();
```

Note that we use `Instant` instead of `ZonedDateTime`, since zone information is irrelevant to us, as long as the time difference is computed correctly. `Instant` always represents the time in UTC, without any *weird* phenomena like *DST*. (Although it does not really matter for this application, it is just cleaner).

Comment: Good Answer. For clarity, I suggest that inside your `scheduleFor` method you convert to using `Instant` rather than `ZonedDateTime` by calling `toInstant`. While it works here in this context, showing `ZonedDateTime.now()` without an explicit time zone sets a bad example to show people learning about date-time handling. Being unaware of the time zone is a common source of trouble in programming. The `Instant` is always in UTC, so its use removes that ambiguity.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the comment, I have a question though. I thought `ChronoUnit#between` is aware of the timezone set in `ZonedDateTime` and will thus compare it correctly, no matter which zone is set in `now()` (which is systems default zone). I.e. it would not matter, the outcome of `between` would always be correct. Is this the case, or am I wrong here?

Comment: I believe **your code *is* correct**, with proper results. As I mentioned in my comment, within the context of your code, your use of `ZonedDateTime` would work successfully. My concern is for other people learning date-time handling, seeing `ZonedDateTime.now()`, and then going on to call that method in their own work, *sans* optional zone argument, without understanding the implications of the JVM’s current default time zone being implicitly applied at runtime. Also, using `Instant` in your method makes clear that we are counting seconds without any specific relevance to time zone issues.